# How to solve mongodb aggregate lookup returning result of all foreign-field in one local-field before opening the other once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've searched the internet and StackOverflow, but I cannot find the answer or even the question.

I have two collections, artisan and users. I want my query to return all reports and indicate if the specified user has that report as a favorite in their array.

**I'm finding hard to remove the other result for the next data that is set in the first result.
i would love to receive some help on how to get the correct value from the aggregate statement.**

**if you look so closely, you will see that "_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787" is showing 3 times, but the correct one is the one with "user_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787" of artisan. That is the same for others also**

**Here below is the code and the result i was getting**

**Thanks**

```
User.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: { 
    from: Artisan.collection.name,
    localField: "user._id",
    foreignField: "artisan.user_id",
    as: "artisan"
  } 
},
{$unwind: '$artisan'}
```

````
])
 .then((result) => {
  res.json(result);
}, (err) => next(err))
.catch((err) => next(err));```  


\\Here is the result

  [
  {
      "_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Ayobami",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$BlfwHzVgZ4kWYfG6Ia4x.Oj6cdVG24Cwl3R9FZQ9lK/1LoUg.WbAi",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.601Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.601Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f788",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.645Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.645Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Ayobami",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$BlfwHzVgZ4kWYfG6Ia4x.Oj6cdVG24Cwl3R9FZQ9lK/1LoUg.WbAi",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.601Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.601Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339194",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "4 years",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339193",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:38:27.998Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:42:22.601Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Ayobami",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$BlfwHzVgZ4kWYfG6Ia4x.Oj6cdVG24Cwl3R9FZQ9lK/1LoUg.WbAi",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.601Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.601Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547e",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547d",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.269Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.269Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339193",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Akinmade",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide1@gmail.com",
      "password": "john1234",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:38:27.957Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:42:22.454Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f788",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.645Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.645Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339193",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Akinmade",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide1@gmail.com",
      "password": "john1234",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:38:27.957Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:42:22.454Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339194",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "4 years",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339193",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:38:27.998Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:42:22.601Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339193",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Akinmade",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide1@gmail.com",
      "password": "john1234",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:38:27.957Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:42:22.454Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547e",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547d",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.269Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.269Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547d",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Akinmade",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide2@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$jg/nKNpg/RkDA.KFG/flFuy8fwfamLdgCD7MNk16rprDiwoWTKcse",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.234Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.234Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f788",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f21f998fe054d2cf0b7f787",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.645Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:35:04.645Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547d",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Akinmade",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide2@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$jg/nKNpg/RkDA.KFG/flFuy8fwfamLdgCD7MNk16rprDiwoWTKcse",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.234Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.234Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339194",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "4 years",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f21fa632fc70100d0339193",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-29T22:38:27.998Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-29T22:42:22.601Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  },
  {
      "_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547d",
      "email_verified": null,
      "sex": "male",
      "phone_no": 2348117741341,
      "address": "10 Oweh Street",
      "area": "",
      "city": "Lagos",
      "state": "Lagos",
      "country": "",
      "job_type": "great work",
      "status": "",
      "login_key": "",
      "login_valid_till": null,
      "firstname": "Johnson",
      "othername": "Akinmade",
      "lastname": "Eniola",
      "email": "ekundayoolumide2@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$jg/nKNpg/RkDA.KFG/flFuy8fwfamLdgCD7MNk16rprDiwoWTKcse",
      "user_type": "artisan",
      "createdAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.234Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.234Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "artisan": {
          "_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547e",
          "date_of_birth": null,
          "duration": "",
          "payment_status": "",
          "payment_type": "",
          "user_id": "5f227b0433105d3a3864547d",
          "createdAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.269Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-30T07:47:16.269Z",
          "__v": 0
      }
  }
]
````

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have:

```
$lookup: { 
    from: Artisan.collection.name,
    localField: "user._id",
    foreignField: "artisan.user_id",
    as: "artisan"
}
```

After looking at your results, the documents from the `User` collection don't have a field named `user._id`, they just have an `_id` field. Similarly with your `Artisan` collection there isn't a field named `artist.user_id`, there's just a `user_id` field. Change the `localField` and `foreignField` values to only have the name of the fields as they appear in the respective documents.

It should look something like this:

```
$lookup: { 
    from: Artisan.collection.name,
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "user_id",
    as: "artisan"
}
```

Comment: When i did what you said, it was giving me empty string on **artisan**

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When i did what you said, it was giving me value of **user** and empty array of **artisan**

artisan: {}

Comment: What do your schemas look like?

Comment: ```const userSchema = new Schema ({ firstname: { type: String, required: true }, othername: { type: String, required: true }, lastname: { type: String, required: true }, email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }); var Users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema); module.exports = Users;```

Comment: ```const artisanSchema = new Schema ({ user_id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }, date_of_birth: { type: Date, default: '' }, duration: { type: String, default: '' }, payment_status: { type: String, default: '' }, payment_type: { type: String, default: '' } },{ timestamps: true }); var Artisans = mongoose.model('Artisan', artisanSchema); module.exports = Artisans; ```